# Delight install issues

Tags: use-package, delight

I want use delight in my `init.el` but I encounter a problem.

Emacs can't install it.

The `init.el` file contain this line : `(use-package delight)`.

But I get this issue : `Error (use-package): Failed to install delight: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Try doing `M-x package-refresh-contents` first?

Comment: ... and try `(use-package delight :ensure t)` to make sure that it is installed, before `use-package` attempts to load it. See the [manual](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages//doc/use-package.html#Installing-packages).

Comment: I believe in combination the aforementioned steps will resolve the issue, but just in case `use-package` isn't working then you can (*after* `package-refresh-contents`) simply `M-x package-install RET delight RET`.  It's in the standard GNU ELPA archive, so that should be all that's needed.